# How do I loop through an array of objects on a click event?

Tags: javascript, arrays, counter, javascript-objects

I am creating a quiz app where the question, answers (an array), and the correct answer are each stored in objects in an array. I am trying to attach an event listener to a button that when clicked, will increment the variable num (which is then used as the index for array of objects) and then display the contents of the next object based on that new index value (which is essentially a counter that counts button click).

My issue is that when I click on the "next" button, the radio buttons and p element displaying the question do not update to the new object questions and choices. I can only assume that the num counter is not actually incrementing on each button click. I have tried to declare the num variable in both global scope and local scope.

Below is my code.

```js
var questionOne = {
  question: "What is the largest naturally occurring element on earth?",

  choices: ["plutonium", "silicon", "uranium", "carbon"],

  correctAnswer: 2
};

var questionTwo = {
  question: "What natural phenomenon causes the sky to be blue and the clouds to be white?",

  choices: ["chromatic polarization", "rayleigh scattering", "solar eclipse", "synchrotron radiation"],

  correctAnswer: 1
};

var questionThree = {
  question: "How many astronomical units is the sun located from the Earth?",

  choices: ["1 au", "91 million mi", "149.6 million km", "8 light minutes"],

  correctAnswer: 0
};

var allQuestions = [questionOne, questionTwo, questionThree];

//store form element in a variable
var quizForm = document.form1;

//put all radio choices in an array
//go through array until you find selected
//return user choice
function getUserChoice() {
  var radios = quizForm.choiceOptions;

  for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
      return radios[i].value;
    }
  }
}

var totalPoints = 0;

//ATTEMPT: increase user points if selected answer matches correctAnswer property
function checkAnswer() {
  if (getUserChoice() == allQuestions.correctAnswer) {
    totalPoints++;
    return totalPoints;
  }
}


var num = 0;

//ATTEMPT: assign label names using for loop //WORKED!! (just call function)
function assignLabelNames() {
  // question counter; update when "next" button is clicked

  num++;
  var questionTitle = document.getElementById("questionFromObject");


  questionTitle.innerText = allQuestions[num].question;

  var labels = document.getElementsByTagName("label");

  for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    labels[i].innerText = allQuestions[num].choices[i];
  }

}

assignLabelNames();

//each time user clicks a radio button, a function is run that cycles through radio buttons and if checked, returns value
for (var i = 0; i < quizForm.radios.length; i++) {
  radios[i].addEventListener("click", getUserChoice());
}

quizForm.btnNext.addEventListener("click", assignLabelNames);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>quiz</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Quiz</h1>
  <p>Select the answer that best answers the question, then click next.</p>
  <form action="" name="form1">
      <p>
      Question <span id="questionNumber">1</span>: <span id="questionFromObject"></span>
      </p>

      <p>
      <input type="radio" id="radioOne" name="choiceOptions">
      <label for="radioOne"></label>
      </p>
      
      <p>
      <input type="radio" id="radioTwo" name="choiceOptions">
      <label for="radioTwo"></label>
   </p>
      
    <p>
    <input type="radio" id="radioThree " name="choiceOptions ">
    <label for="radioThree"></label>
   </p>
      
   <p>
    <input type="radio" id="radioFour " name="choiceOptions ">
    <label for="radioFour"></label>
   </p>

   <input type="button" name="btnBack " value="back ">

   <input type="button" name="btnNext " value="next ">

  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `radios[i].addEventListener("click", getUserChoice());` => don't call getUserChoice(), just reference it. Change it to: `radios[i].addEventListener("click", getUserChoice);`

Comment: sorry, still working on that functionality. I was going to correct all that as soon as I could display a new question and answer on a button click. The quiz is still very much incomplete.

Comment: `quizForm.` is missing before radios[i] inside the loop

Comment: yeah. but that's the problem. JS breaks if there is code that isn't valid. remove the for-loop (`for (var i = 0; i < quizForm.radios.length; i++) { ... }`) and it's working

Comment: I love you. Seriously, thank you, for you that.

Comment: One more thing, can you explain why exactly that solves the issue?

Comment: Press Ctrl + Shift + J and you have access to the browser console. Without commenting the for-loop out you can see an error message listed in the console. Errors can break the javascript execution. `quizForm.radios` doesn't exists, so it throws the error.

Comment: Thanks once again Joshua K. Totally fixed my issue.

Comment: a little bit of code for you :) sorted your code and fixed some errors:https://jsfiddle.net/Kasalop/xaduen9n/

Comment: Stop everything you're doing and learn how to debug JavaScript code. This is the most important skill for you to pick up right now. Sure, you can post a question on SO and often get an answer within minutes, but when you learn to debug, you'll most often be able to find the answer yourself in less time that it would have taken to post the question. In particular, learn how to step through your code in a debugger. You can stop at every statement and look at everything to find out exactly what the code is doing. See this [guide to the Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools).

Comment: Joshua K your code is incredible. I will study it and see how I can incorporate some of your methods in future projects I work on. Michael Geary, thanks for the advice. I am working through the console debugging lesson that you linked to right now.